Why isn't my class unloaded when I erase any link to them and to ClassLoader?
I am trying to learn how class unloading works in Java. I have created a test application that just loads a class, and than waits.
package com.expirement;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception {
        f();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        //breakpoint
    }
    public static void f() throws Exception {
        URLClassLoader cl=new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{
            Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
        });
        Class<?> c = cl.loadClass ("com.expirement.Loadable1");
        cl.close();
        System.gc();
        cl = null;
        c = null;
    }
}

Unfortunately, on that breakpoint the JVM hasn't unloaded the class.
My questions are:

Why has the class not been unloaded?
What to do so that it can finally destroy the class (without stopping the runtime)?


There is no guaranty that System.gc() does anything nor that class unloading will happen. But your chances are higher when you set the variables to null before running System.gc(). Further, check whether c.getClassLoader() == cl as you assume. I think, the default delegation parent is the application class loader and since the parent loader has a class of that name (the loaders load from the same URL), I’d expect the returned class to be loaded by the application class loader.

@Holger, thanks a lot, you have just clairified the situation a bit. I've checked, you are right about ApplicationClassLoader. Now, how can I avoid loading the class by it?

Specify a parent class loader, e.g. to use the bootstrap loader, use URLClassLoader cl=new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{ Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation() }, null);

@Holger, that worked. Please write this as an answer, so I can appreciate your help (upvote).

When you do not specify a parent loader, the URLClassLoader will use the application class loader and since you are using a URL from the classpath, the requested class can be resolved through this parent loader.
You can specify the bootstrap loader (represented as null) as the parent loader.
Note further that the chances of the objects getting collected are higher when you set the variables to null or leave the method containing them before you trigger the garbage collection.
For example:
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ReferenceQueue<Class<?>> queue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
        WeakReference<Class<?>> ref = f(queue);
        do System.gc(); while(queue.remove(1000) != ref);
        System.out.println("class has been collected");
    }

    public static
        WeakReference<Class<?>> f(ReferenceQueue<Class<?>>queue) throws Exception {

        URL url = Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
        try(URLClassLoader cl=new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{ url }, null)) {
           Class<?> c = cl.loadClass("com.expirement.Loadable1");
           return new WeakReference<>(c, queue);
        }
    }
}

But always keep in mind that this is not guaranteed to collect the class. System.gc() is just a hint that might get ignored by the JVM, but even when the garbage collector runs, it does not guaranty that all objects get collected, and finally, class unloading is an optional feature, which is not supported by every JVM and can be turned off in some implementations.

BTW, is there a way to make my URLClassLoader behave exactly like an ApplicationClassLoader (load classes from the same sources), but without setting it to parent?

You can use System.getProperty("java.class.path") , split it according to File.pathSeparator and construct all URLs for a URLClassLoader. But starting with Java 9, the application class loader is not a URLClassLoader anymore und has an entirely different mechanism for loading classes of modules. I don’t think that trying to copy the application class loader is a good approach. Rather, separate the code that manages class loading and unloading from the code that ought to be loaded dynamically. Don’t make the latter available to the application class loader (i.e. class path) at all.

Ok. So where should I put my code so the ApplicationClassLoader can't reach it? I want it to still be in my jar file.

You can put the classes into a subdirectory within the jar file. Then, use a jar:path-to-jar!/subdir/ URL for your URLClassLoader.

But ApplicationClassLoader can scan entire jar-file, can't it? I suppose it will think about them as about packages.

A class loader does not scan the entire file. It will only search for actually requested classes. And even when you ask it load a class like subdir.some.Class, it would reject it, because the name stored in the class file (some.Class) does not match. You could go a step further and choose a name that can’t match a package name part, e.g. sub.dir. Then, it wouldn’t even find the class files on request. But normally you don’t need such precaution as there will never be any load request for those classes. Newer Java versions even use this trick themselves for versioning.
